# A fully open-source software LAMP-like stack for GPGPU?

Tags: open-source, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

There is a lot of open-source options for web developers. For example, the LAMP stack is fully open-source and if you build you software on it you are not dependent on different vendors, proprietary licenses, etc.

Does something similar exist for general-purpose computing on graphics processing units?

CUDA is definitely not open-sourced, OpenCL is just an open standard, but the compiler is proprietary (right?).

[Brook](http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/brookgpu/index.html)? Deprecated [Sh](http://libsh.org/index.html)?

Anything else?

Does any 'Linux - gcc - video_driver - ?GPGPU' open-source software stack exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [PTX backend for LLVM](http://sites.google.com/site/justinholewinski/projects/llvm-ptx-back-end), but to get runnable binary you still need proprietary NVCC compiler, and proprietary nVidia video driver to run it.

BrookGPU and Sh both use shaders as their backend, so they are far from having all capabilities of "real" GPGPU platforms (like CUDA or OpenCL) and, I guess, have poorer performance. And, at least Brook, requires proprietary drivers to run. Also, latest update to [Brook project on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brook/) is dated Feb. 2010, so this project is quite dead too.

OpenCL, despite being open standard, indeed have proprietary compilers (in case of nVidia the compiler is bundled with driver, for AMD/ATI and Intel it can be downloaded separately). Of course one can develop free compiler, but as far as I know, right now there is no open hardware GPGPU architecture (at last wide used one: both nVidia and ATI keep their architecture details unavailable to public). And we can be sure that command set is quite different between different architectures, so for each architecture one want to support, one would have to reverse engineer it (and I guess it might violate license agreement, not sure though). I've heard some attempts were made by [nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/) team, but with no any visible results.